# Raspberry Pi 2, PIR project, all pins always get GPIO.HIGH value

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I folowing this tutorial
https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/raspberrypi-to-detect-movement-using-pir-motion-sensor-hc-sr501/11/21/2014/

and a little bit simplified my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Info - This program is for PIR sensor. Contionusly checks for state, 
#        set LED if movement detected and plays wav file on detection.

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


PIR = 7     # On-board pin number 7 (GPIO04)

state = False
val = False

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)    # Change this if using GPIO numbering
GPIO.setup(PIR, GPIO.IN)    # Set PIR as input

try:
    while True:
        val = GPIO.input(PIR)       # read input value
        if (val == True):       # check if the input is HIGH
            print("Hi there!")
            time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I also have wiringpi library, so when i do gpio readall I see that pin 7 gets 0 or 1 dependes on sensor data. but when i run python code, it just gets 1 all the time, and prints "Hi there" all the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know low is not being detected? Why not print something out if val is not True?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the PIR device should assert a voltage or ground depending on the state of the device,  you should try to add `pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN` to your `GPIO.setup` call as does one of the examples I found using Python.

In fact, the C code you link to appears to also do this (although the C code sets `PID_UP`):

```
bcm2835_gpio_set_pud(SENSOR, BCM2835_GPIO_PUD_UP);
```

See [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/parent-detector/worksheet/) and [this](http://raspberry.io/projects/view/reading-and-writing-from-gpio-ports-from-python/) for more information.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

sensor = 4

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state = False
current_state = False

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    previous_state = current_state
    current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
    if current_state != previous_state:
        new_state = "HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
        print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, new_state))
```

Reading more on this you may need to set `GPIO.PUD_UP`.

This [this comment](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=87292&p=614759) for more information on when to use `GPIO.PUD_UP` versus `GPIO.PUD_DOWN`:

> by joan » Thu Sep 18, 2014 7:07 am An input gpio will float between 0
>   and 1 if it's not connected to a voltage.
>
> The pull-up/downs supply that voltage so that the gpio will have a
>   defined value UNTIL overridden by a stronger force.
>
> You should set a pull-down (to 0) when you expect the stronger force
>   to pull it up to 1.
>
> You should set a pull-up (to 1) when you expect the stronger force to
>   pull it down to 0.
>
> Otherwise the gpio will not change state and you'll never know about
>   the external event.

Comment: I do not see that adding a pull-up or down will make any difference.  The PIR will be driving the line high when an object is detected and low when nothing is seen, it will not be floating.

Comment: **If it's not connected to a voltage.**  The PIR is supplying a voltage.